# Can't load PDF files larger than 2MB with JS

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

My question is almost the same to the following post
[Certain PDF files won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612916/certain-pdf-files-wont-open) but in my case is simpler. I can't load PDF files larger than 2MB, with smaller files works fine.

When I use *readAsDataURL* method, the *reader.result* would seem to be sliced. I made comparition between base64 generated by the example below (my case) and online tool that works fine, to my bse64 missing the last part (a big one).

If someone knows something about this behaviour and can give me  a hint i will be grateful.

My code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="height: 100%;">
    <button onclick="getFile(event)">Get File</button>
    <input id="pdfInputFile" type="file" accept="application/pdf" style="display:none" onchange="loadPDF(this);" />
    <object id="pdfViewer" type="application/pdf" style="height:100%; width:100%;border:solid 1px" >
    </object>
</body>

<script>

    function getFile(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("pdfInputFile").click();
    }


    function loadPDF(input) {
        
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById("pdfViewer").setAttribute('data', reader.result);
            }

           reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are certain limits to dataurls, on some browsers this is 2MB. An alternative would be to use BLOB-urls as described here: [Data protocol URL size limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695151/data-protocol-url-size-limitations).

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution for file system PDF files (was my case)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="height: 100%;">
    <button onclick="getFile(event)">Get File</button>
    <input id="pdfInputFile" type="file" accept="application/pdf" style="display:none" onchange="loadPDF(this);" />
    <object id="pdfViewer" type="application/pdf" style="height:100%; width:100%;border:solid 1px" >
    </object>
</body>

<script>

    function getFile(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("pdfInputFile").click();
    }


    function loadPDF(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            showFile(input.files[0])
        }
    }

    function showFile(blob){

        // It is necessary to create a new blob object with mime-type explicitly set
        // otherwise only Chrome works like it should
        var newBlob = new Blob([blob], {type: "application/pdf"});

        // Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
        const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);        
        document.getElementById("pdfViewer").setAttribute('data', data);
        setTimeout(function(){
            // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
        }, 100);
    }

</script>
</html>
```